# Rails Internationalization (I18n) in model validations: Possible or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, internationalization, model, production-environment

I have the following validation in a model:

```
validates_inclusion_of :whatever, :in => [true, false], :message => I18n.t('please_select_whatever')
```

It seems that the translation does not work in production mode: in all languages it's always the english translation that gets diplayed (probably because I set english as the default locale in my app...?).

So I am assuming that we can't translate validations in models, because models get loaded only once - when the server is booted (and then, the default locale would be applied).

Am I right? If yes, how would you solve this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The solution is to NOT include any *custom* message keys in the models, like...

```
:message => I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.my_model.attributes.whatever.please_select_whatever')
```

The model will then apply the default message keys, for example ":inclusion" in the case of "validates_inclusion_of"

...and in config/locales/en.yml you need to have:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        my_model:
          attributes:
            whatever:
              inclusion: "Please select whatever." # see default key: "inclusion"
```

for reference, check out the respective Rails guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: I always forget the defaults for the activerecord error messages (and I need them every few months or so), thankfully Google helps me find this answer over and over again!

Comment: => The better way to approach this problem is the answer by @iain below.

Comment: This doesn't address *why* OPs solution didn't work: the translation was interpreted when the project _initialized_, which happens every request in dev, but only once at boot in prod. To support multiple languages they must be interpreted at _runtime_, which @iain's solution addresses. TomDogg's solution only works if you can use the same default translation in every case, which isn't always the best UX.

Comment: For error messages, [this is a better link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation)

Answer (score 18):

You can use symbols, to specify translations:

```
validates_inclusion_of :whatever, :in => [true, false], :message => :select_whatever
```

And it will be translated with a particular scope. See the [I18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) for more details.

Comment: The part following ":message =>" should be something along the lines of: I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.[model_name].attributes.[attribute_name]')

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. I suspect that in Rails, it is not possible to have translations in models (since they only get loaded once).

Comment: Use a Symbol as I did and place the translation in the appropriate place (as indicated in the guide). Don't call I18n.t here. My example is right.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm on Rails 2.3. I suppose your solution works for Rails 3, but not for Rails 2.3?

Comment: It works on Rails 2.2 and upwards and I know for sure, because I contributed to that part.

Comment: Thanks for getting back - It's strange b/C When I do as you say, I still get "undefined method `select_whatever' for model...", which leads me to think Rails doesn't accept a symbol in that place...

Comment: what if I need to send a variable to the i18n string. e.g.  "the value %{value} is invalid" ?

Answer (score 5):

OK, `iain` answer works, but I took very long time to figure out where should I put the `:select_whatever`.

`validates_inclusion_of :whatever, :in => [true, false], :message => :select_whatever`

OK your `en.yml` should look like this:

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      select_whatever: "error!!"
```