# Error for ln18 translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For test reasons i tried:

```
I18n.locale = "fehler_ausgabe"
puts I18n.translate "activerecord.attributes.diagnosis.sicherheit"
```

What worked correctly and returned `E-mail addresse` for this yaml-file:

```
fehler_ausgabe:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      diagnosis:
        sicherheit: "E-mail addresse"
```

Next i tried to test a error that is in my model defined like this:

```
validates :sicherheit, inclusion: { in: ["U","V"]}, unless: :skip_fehler
```

I changed my yaml file:

```
fehler_ausgabe:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      diagnosis:
        sicherheit: "E-mail addresse"
          inclusion: "muss zugeorndet werden"
```

I tried again:

```
puts I18n.translate "activerecord.attributes.diagnosis.sicherheit"
```

But now  somehow get this error:

```
I18n::InvalidLocaleData (can not load translations from C:/Sites/heroku
2/config/locales/fehler_ausgabe.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError:     (C:/Sites/heroku2/config/locales/fehler_ausgabe.yml): 
did not find expected key while parsin
g a block mapping at line 5 column 9>):
```

What do i wrong? I dont understand why my code now throws a error! THANKS

Comment: Your change makes YAML file with invalid data. You can not have `inclusion:` in `sicherheit: "E-mail addresse"` either remove "E-mail addresse" or `inclusion`.

Comment: could you please respond in a answer so that i can mark  it as correct ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your change:

```
fehler_ausgabe:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      diagnosis:
        sicherheit: "E-mail addresse"
          inclusion: "muss zugeorndet werden"
```

makes your YAML file invalid. You can not have `inclusion: "muss zugeorndet werden"` if you tend to have `sicherheit: "E-mail addresse"`. Either remove `inclusion: "muss zugeorndet werden"` or `"E-mail addresse"` to make your arrangement work.

However, you can [checkout this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453350/645886) to setup `inclusion` validation properly in your YAML.