# Rails validates doesn't accept custom message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have the following validation:

```
validates :email, format: { with: Devise::email_regexp, message: I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.client.attributes.email.invalid') }
```

The problem is, it is now showing the error message I specify there. It shows the default one.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i18n should not be included in the model, but rather in a YAML file.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        my_model:
          attributes:
            whatever:
              inclusion: "Please select whatever." # see default key: "inclusion"
```

See more detailed answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453350/763799)

Comment: Thank you, great answer. The chart on this link has all the information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models